# Issue with Sitecore Content Multi Lingual Tagging: "Could not perform tagging, Providers list is empty" message and warning

Tags: sitecore-api

I have successfully configured content tagging in Sitecore for the "English" language content. However, I am facing an issue where it is not working for "Japanese" language content. I have provided the configuration details below.

**Configuration Patch file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
 <sitecore>
 <settings>
 <setting name="Sitecore.ContentTagging.OpenCalais.CalaisEndpoint" value="https://permid.org/api/calais" />
 <setting name="Sitecore.ContentTagging.OpenCalais.CalaisAccessToken" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
 <setting name="Sitecore.ContentTagging.OpenCalais.CalaisLanguage" value="Japanese" />
 </settings>
</sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Upon encountering the following message:
"Could not perform tagging, Providers list is empty,"
[image]

along with a warning stating: "There were warnings during tagging. Please consult your system administrator for further details."

[image]

Can you please review and let me know if I missed anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I've got it working now by adding language IDs under the **"languages"** node in the **"Sitecore.ContentTagging.OpenCalais.config"** configuration file. Check out the sample configurations below.

**full path :**

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\your instance name\App_Config\Sitecore\ContentTagging\Sitecore.ContentTagging.OpenCalais.config

```
<openCalais>
        <languages>
          <language id="ja"/>
          <language id="en"/>
          <language id="vi"/>         
        </languages>
      </openCalais>
```

You can obtain the valid language IDs from the **"C:\inetpub\wwwroot\your instance name\App_Config\LanguageDefinitions.config"** configuration file.